# ssh-agent across ssh sessions on shared host

Tags: ssh-agent

I ssh into a shared host (WebFaction) and then use `ssh-agent` to establish a connection to a mercurial repository (BitBucket). I call the agent like so:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

This then spews out the pid of the agent and sets its relevant environment variables. I then use ssh-add as follows to add my identity (after typing my passphrase):

```
ssh-add /path/to/a/key
```

My ssh connection eventually times out and I'm disconnected from the server. When I log back in, I can no longer connect to the Hg server and so I do this:

```
ps aux | grep 1234.*ssh-agent`
kill -SIGHUP 43210
```

And then repeat the two commands at the top of the post (ie. invoke the agent using `eval` and call `ssh-add`).

I'm sure that there's a well established idiom for avoiding this process and maintaining a "reference" to the agent that was spawned initially. I've tried redirecting I/O of the first command to a file (in the hope of sourcing it in my `.bashrc`), but I only get the agent's pid.

How can I avoid having to go through this process each time I ssh into the host?

My *NIX skills are weak, so constructive criticism on any aspect of the post is welcome, not just my use of `ssh-agent`.

Comment: You probably want to only run your agent locally and use [agent forwarding](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+agent+forwarding) instead.

Comment: I've never worked with BitBucket, but agent forwarding works fine with Github.  I'd imagine that git-over-ssh and hg-over-ssh aren't that dis-similar.  Honestly, it should Just Work(tm), given that agent forwarding is a ssh thing.

Comment: Time to upgrade to a VPS instead of shared hosting?

Comment: Yeah, I've been down that road with [Linode](http://www.linode.com) and EC2. All-in-all, I'm satisfied with the level of access and service that [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com) provides. 
In hindsight, I probably should have posted this to ServerFault. Going to flag it for migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

With ssh-agent running locally and identities added, `ssh -A user@host.webfaction.com` provides the secure shell on the remote host with the local agent's identities.

Long answer:

As Charles suggested, [agent forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#fwd) is the solution.

At first, I thought that I could just issue an `ssh user@host.webfaction.com` and then, from within the secure session on the remote host, connect to the BitBucket repository using hg+ssh. But that failed, and so I investigated the [ForwardAgent and AgentForwardingEnabled flags](https://superuser.com/questions/168933/extra-configuration-required-for-ssh-agent-forwarding/280938#280938).

Thinking that I'd have to settle for a workaround in .bashrc that involved keeping my private key on the remote host, I went looking for a shell-script solution but was spared from this kludge by this [answer in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/249712/18898), which is perfect and works without any client configuration (I'm not sure how the sshd server is configured on WebFaction).

Aside: in my question, I posted the following:

```
ps aux | grep 1234.*ssh-agent`
kill -SIGHUP 43210
```

but this is actually inefficient and requires the user to know his/her uid (available via `/etc/passwd`). `pgrep` is much easier:

```
pgrep -u username process-name
```